# Why the ID of iptables trace records is zero?

Tags: networking, iptables

I used iptables trace to analysis an network problem, but the ID of records of ACK packets was always zero:

```
[ 3556.086666] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=lo SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=80 SYN      
[ 3556.086772] TRACE: nat:OUTPUT:rule:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=80 SYN      
[ 3556.086784] TRACE: nat:KUBE-SERVICES:rule:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=80 SYN      
[ 3556.086793] TRACE: nat:KUBE-MARK-MASQ:rule:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=80 SYN      
[ 3556.086803] TRACE: nat:KUBE-MARK-MASQ:return:2 IN= OUT=lo SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=80 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086814] TRACE: nat:KUBE-SERVICES:rule:2 IN= OUT=lo SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=80 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086825] TRACE: nat:KUBE-NODE-PORT:return:2 IN= OUT=lo SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=80 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086846] TRACE: nat:KUBE-SERVICES:rule:3 IN= OUT=lo SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=80 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086891] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:rule:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.22.46.48 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=30080 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086900] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.22.46.48 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=30080 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086918] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.22.46.48 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=30080 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086928] TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:rule:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.22.46.48 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=30080 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086939] TRACE: nat:KUBE-POSTROUTING:rule:3 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.22.46.48 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=30080 SYN      MARK=0x4000 
[ 3556.086948] TRACE: nat:KUBE-POSTROUTING:rule:4 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.233.52.186 DST=10.22.46.48 ID=51512  PROTO=TCP SPT=54186 DPT=30080 SYN      
[ 3556.087562] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.22.46.11 ID=0  PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=39830 SYN    
[ 3556.087592] TRACE: filter:INPUT:rule:1 IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=0  PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=54186 SYN    
[ 3556.087606] TRACE: filter:KUBE-NODE-PORT:return:2 IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=0  PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=54186 SYN    
[ 3556.087617] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=10.22.46.48 DST=10.233.52.186 ID=0  PROTO=TCP SPT=30080 DPT=54186 SYN
```

Why?

Comment: Because a Don't Fragment (DF) packet's IPv4 ID value MUST be ignored. So it can be set to anything including 0. A firewall that would not like this value is a broken firewall.

Comment: Why are you asking this? XY problem?

Comment: @A.B Because I have a packet loss problem and the ACK packet's trace record's ID is zero,  so I want to what caused this.

Comment: If you want an answer explaining why the id 0 is not an error and is not an anomaly, that's fine, but it won't help about the packet loss, unless you have an other reason to believe it's caused by an other part. I know of at least a Q/A where OP knew that wasn't an error but had a *faulty* network component which dropped id=0.

Comment: @A.B I just wanna know why ID is zero, the packet loss problem is caused by another component, but ID=0 make me hard to trace packets. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I guess you have encapsulated traffic and rely on the inherit id without having to decode traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details are described in [RFC 6864](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6864): Updated Specification of the IPv4 ID Field. All quotes below are from this RFC, not necessarily in order.

The IPv4 ID field is used to distinguish two fragments with the same offset but belonging to two different packets, when doing reassembly. When there is no fragment, there is nothing special to take care of.

As SYN and SYN/ACK both have the Don't Fragment (DF) flag set, there can't be a fragment, so the ID become useless:

> >> IPv4 datagrams whose DF=1 MUST NOT be fragmented.

> o  Atomic datagrams: (DF==1)&&(MF==0)&&(frag_offset==0)

> **In atomic datagrams**, the IPv4 ID field has no meaning; thus, it can
> be set to an arbitrary value, i.e., **the requirement for non-repeating
> IDs within the source address/destination address/protocol tuple is
>
> no longer required for atomic datagrams**:
>
> >> Originating sources MAY set the IPv4 ID field of atomic
> datagrams to any value.

Linux just uses 0 for all SYN/ACKs as long as they have the DF flag (I'm not considering *TCP Fast Open* which might change this when the SYN/ACK also includes actual data).

> This requires that IDs be unique within the source address/destination
> address/protocol tuple when fragmentation is possible (e.g., DF=0) or
> when it has already occurred (e.g., frag_offset>0 or MF=1).

> This document thus defines this field's value only for fragmentation
> and reassembly:
>
> >> **The IPv4 ID field MUST NOT be used for purposes other than
> fragmentation and reassembly**.

The RFC 6864 explicitly states that one shouldn't rely on the ID for traffic identification.

> >> Originating sources MAY set the IPv4 ID field of atomic
> datagrams to any value.

> >> All devices that examine IPv4 headers **MUST ignore the IPv4 ID
> field of atomic datagrams**.

---

### Bonus

Provide a very limited way to identify the traffic. This requires *nftables* (*iptables* can't do this). One can't manipulate directly the IP fields with payload mangling or the IP checksum is not recalculated properly. So it's limited to assigning the ID value once with a single `ip id set` which does recalculate checksum properly. As the rvalue must not be typed (eg: `@th,16,16` gets type `tcp dport`), I choose to reuse the 15 lower bits of the client's source port (`@th,17,15` stays an integer), which is the destination port in the SYN/ACK:

`customsynackid.nft`:

```
table ip customsynackid        # for idempotence
delete table ip customsynackid # for idempotence

table ip customsynackid {
    chain prerouting { type filter hook prerouting priority -310; policy accept;
    ip frag-off & 0x4000 != 0 tcp flags syn|ack ip id == 0 ip id set @th,17,15
    }
}
```

This is intended to be done on a router, eg: the K8s node, and could be complemented by selecting the interface(s) where it should be applied, possibly even in *postrouting* instead of *prerouting*. It can be done on an end node (eg: the pod if it had the capabilities to use *nftables* which it won't) just by replacing `hook prerouting` with `hook output`.

This sets the [id field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#Header) to ([tcp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) dport & 0x7fff). For example a reply to a TCP connection from port 37142 to port 80 (thus from port 80 to port 37142) would give a SYN/ACK with an id field of 4374 (37142 & 0x7fff = 4374).